# Emplacing vector into map

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

Given this type:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<T>> map;
```

How to directly emplace elements?

```
map.emplace(10, /* ? */);
```

I can do it by separately creating the vector first, and then using that identifier in the call to emplace, but that is undesirable in case it's possible to do it directly somehow.

Comment: Related (and possibly a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634223/how-to-use-emplace-in-a-stdmap-whose-value-is-a-stdset-map-from-something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `piecewise_construct` with `std::make_tuple`:

```c++
map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple(5), std::make_tuple(10, 3));
```

Comment: And don't ever say that C++ isn't intuitive or that it makes your computer program hard to read. _:droll:_

Comment: It's clear that the intention is to initialize `map[5]` with a vector containing 10 elements, each initialized to 3. Right?

Comment: I take back what I said regarding how it's more desirable to emplace it directly.

Comment: This example doesn't cover when you want to pass a raw pointer to the vector. It should :)

Answer (score 8):

Both

```
map.emplace(typename decltype(map)::value_type(10, {1, 2, 3}));
```

and

```
map.emplace(10, std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3});
```

should work fine.

I'm sure there is a reason why gcc rejects my first attempt:

```
map.emplace(10, {1, 2, 3});
```

but I don't know if it is a good reason or a defect.

**Edit:** It seems to have to do with the fact that the braced initializer list (`{1, 2, 3}`) does not have a type, making it impossible to use with perfect forwarding (which is necessary for `map.emplace`). There are several relevant SO posts about this point, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28634397/1566221).

Comment: I think it's because `emplace` has lots of magic to make the "overloads" work, and thus it can't deduce the types correctly.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yeah, I think so too. The question is whether its a bug in gcc or the standard library bundled with gcc or whether the standard permits it. I seem to have borked my clang install so I can't test.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Thanks. According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/28634397/1566221, the problem is that braced initializer lists cannot be perfect forwarded.

Comment: it's also worth noting that `map.insert` doesn't have this issue.

Comment: @MooingDuck: which adds credibility to the claim that it has to do with forwarding. `map.insert` doesn't need to forward, so it can just let the `std::vector` be constructed with an implicit conversion.